# $wpdb how to use replace()?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a form that submits some data to the database but I need to be able check if the row already exists if it does I want to update that row if not I want to insert a new row. I know that you can use replace() for this but I can't get it to work.

Here's my code;

```
$wpdb->replace('wp_tshirts', array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'type' => $shirt_type,
    'size' => sanitize_text_field($shirt_size),
    'name' => $shirt_name
));
```

Comment: "I can't get it to work". Why? Are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: @cabrerahector It just creates a new row even if the row already exists

Comment: It might be due to the format of the data you're passing into the function. In your `wp_shirts` table, is the `user_id` field a string or an integer? (same question goes for the rest of the fields)

Comment: See s_ha_dum's [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145007/wpdb-insert-or-if-exists-update) . It would mean replacing the helper wpdb function however.

Comment: Is one of the columns you provide a unique key in your table?